# simple html dom parser: fix missing quotes of attributes

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

i'm using simple html dom parser for batch-fixing errors in html markup, such as missing quotes like

```
<div class=foo></div>
```

my code:

```
$els = $doc->find("div[class]");
foreach($els as $el)
{
    $class = $el->getAttribute("class");
    $el->setAttribute("class", "\"".$class."\"");
}
```

it works, but the drawback is it does not work for elements which already have quotes, so eg. `<div class="foo"></div>` will result in `<div class='"foo"'></div>` which seems to be a bug for me.
i also can't check if the class is quoted or not as the parser only returns the string without quotes and i also don't want to work with outertext as there might be other attributes which would have to be considered.

any ideas how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: You do realize that those very quotes are optional in HTML? And if you were using XHTML (or possibly utilizing), `tidy` or `htmLawed` or `HTMLPurifier` would be better options than SHD.

Comment: Or just load it with DomDocument and then dump it, the quotes will get added.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to reset the attributes as strings, as apparently, the double quotes are stripped if an attribute is not a string.

So for future reference and other people, you could do:

```
$els = $doc->find("div[class]");
foreach($els as $el) {
    $class = $el->getAttribute("class");
    $el->setAttribute("class", strval($class));
}
```

or you could try setting all attributes as strings:

```
    foreach($html->find('your selector here') as $elem) {
        
        # check if there are attributes
        if (is_object($elem) && isset($elem->attr)) {
            
            # loop through all attributes
            foreach ($elem->attr as $key=>$val) {
                    
                # normalize attributes, but skip empty, integers and boolean values
                if(!empty($val) && !is_int($val) && !is_bool($val)) {
                    $elem->{$key} = strval($elem->{$key});
                }   
            }                   
        }
    }
```